# Exclusion by annotation not working for sbt test/testOnly

Tags: sbt, scalatest

Consider the following `org.scalatest.TagAnnotation` subclass:

```
public class TestSizeTags {

    /** Tests with crazy long runtimes **/
    @org.scalatest.TagAnnotation
    @Inherited
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
    public static @interface HugeTestClass {}

}
```

Let us `annotate`/`tag` a class with it:

```
@HugeTestClass
class ItemsJobTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterEach with DataFrameSuiteBase {
```

Now we want a quick "smoke test suite" on the codebase; therefore, let us (*attempt*) to *exclude* the testcases annotated by `HugeTestClass` :

Command line:

```
sbt test * -- -l HugeTestClass
```

OR maybe:

```
sbt 'testOnly * -- -l HugeTestClass'
```

Let us also attempt it within sbt itself:

```
sbt> testOnly * -- -l HugeTestClass
```

In *all* cases above we (unfortunately) still see:

```
[info] ItemsJobTest:
^C[info] - Run Items Pipeline *** FAILED *** (2 seconds, 796 milliseconds)
```

So the test actually *did* run.. contrary to the intention.

So what is the correct syntax / approach to apply a `Tag Filter(/Exclusion)` via `sbt` to `scalatest` classes?

Comment: I have used scala `Tag` to include or exclude, eg. `object HugeTestClassTag extends org.scalatest.Tag("DatabaseTest")` then add  `HugeTestClassTag` to my test methods. By the way should `HugeTestClass` be static class for you?

Comment: @prayagupd  Yes it is static: updated the OP to show it is an inner class

Comment: try putting your testOnly part in double quote, also give full package to Tag to ignore.

Comment: @prayagupd Same behavior.

Comment: Dammit. I posted one working example in answer. Same there? Its working for me. Two things missing were 1) `""` and 2) full package to `HugeTestClass` while excecuting.

Comment: Well, does not work with static tag `TestSizeTags.HugeTestClass`

Comment: @prayagupd OK i'll try it in own class not in static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to put the `testOnly` part in double quote and also give full package to the Tag Annotation to ignore,

```
sbt "test-only * -- -l full.package.to.HugeTestClass"
```

example,

**Tag annotation**

```
package tags;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@org.scalatest.TagAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface ExcludeMePleaseTag {}
```

**Test to exclude**

```
@tags.ExcludeMePleaseTag
class ExcludeMeSpecs extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "I" should " not run" in {

    888 shouldBe 1
  }

}
```

**to exclude the tests**

```
sbt "test-only * -- -l tags.ExcludeMePleaseTag"
```

This github issue was helpful - https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/357#issuecomment-44867814

**But it does not work with static Tag annotation,**

```
public class WrapperClass {

    @org.scalatest.TagAnnotation
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
    public static @interface ExcludeMePleaseTag {
    }

}

sbt "test-only * -- -l tags.WrapperClass.ExcludeMePleaseTag"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info: will try the Tag as top level not inner class.

Comment: Great buddy, scala does not like static in some cases, I don't have good explanation for this one though.

Comment: Why `--` in `sbt "test-only * -- -l tags.ExcludeMePleaseTag"`? And if I don't specify `--` in sbt command, tagged tests are not excluded.

Comment: @TarangBhalodia `--` tells the test-only command that there are no more test class arguments, allowing `-l tags.ExcludeMePleaseTag` to be passed as options.